# Existe en dart una función similar o igual a distinct()?

Tags: flutter, dart

Me gustaría saber si existe una función como la de distinct() en Flutter o similar .

Mi lista seria parecida a esta:

```
List<String> list = ['abc',"abc",'def'];
```

La salida me gustaría que fuera :

```
[abc,def]
```

Comment: Hi @RogerCuesta. This site is spanish site of StackOverflow. Please, translate your question and we'll can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de esta forma sin necesidad de usar paquetes externos:

```
  List<String> list = ['abc',"abc",'def'];
    var distinctList = list.toSet().toList();
    print(distinctList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenes varias opciones, una sería

```
final newList = [];
Observable
   .fromList(['abc', 'abc', 'def'])
   .distinct()
   .observe((next) => newList.add(next), () => print(newList));
```

Otra podría ser usando [queries](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/queries) package

```
import 'package:queries/collections.dart';

void main() {
  List<String> list = ["abc", "abc","def"];
  var result = new Collection(list).distinct();
  print(result.toList());
}
```

saludos

Comment: Cuando intento importar el paquete de Queries me dice : depends on queries >=0.0.17 which requires SDK version >=2.0.0-dev.60.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed. Mi versión es esta : he current Dart SDK version is 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760. Ya pase a la versión DEV pero me sigue con el problema de versión .